# A curious integration problem : the antiderivative is known but not the definite integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Working [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686138/require-a-solution-numerically-or-analytically-to-a-tricky-trigonometric-integ/4686613?noredirect=1#comment9913139_4686613) on Mathematics Stack Exchange, I face the problem of computing
$$I(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{a \sin ^2(k)+b}{\sqrt{\left(a \sin
   ^2(k)+b\right)^2+\sin ^2(k)}}\,dk$$ where $(a,b)$ are positive constants $( 0 <b<\frac 1 4a)$ and $0<t\leq \frac \pi 2$.

Mathematica produces almost instantly the antiderivative in terms of elliptic integrals of the first and third kinds. However, no result for the definite integral (all above assumptions being provided).

$I(0)=0$ is immediately returned but asking for $I\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$ Mathematica runs for even (I let my computer running $14$ hours for no result.

I suppose that the problem comes from the fact that the argument of the elliptic integrals is proportional to $\tan(k)$.

So, **my question** :   `is there any way to obtain the limit ?`

```
    Integrate[(a Sin[t]^2 +b)/((a Sin[t]^2+b)^2+Sin[t]^2)^(1/2),{t,0,Pi/2}]
```

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code. This will increase chance to get helpful answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version (*"12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"*)
```

The definite  integral evaluates to

```
int = Values@DSolve[{f'[k] == (a Sin[k]^2 + b)/Sqrt[(a Sin[k]^2 + b)^2 + Sin[k]^2 ], f[0] == 0}, f, k][[1, 1]]
```

Unfortunately `Asymptotic[int[k],k->Pi/2]` doesn't evaluate.

With the help of  substitution `Tan[k]->tank`

```
subst = Join[{Tan[k] -> tank},Table[Cos[i k] -> (Cos[i k] /. k -> ArcTan[tank] // TrigExpand), {i,1,4}]] // Simplify;
```

we get asymptotic of `k->Pi/2`

```
Asymptotic[int[k] /. subst, tank -> Infinity] //Simplify[#, Assumptions -> {tank > 0, 0 < b < a/4}] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I arrived to the point where I obtained (with your code) $-\frac{2 \sqrt{b^2}}{b \text{uk}}$ but I do not understand the next step. What do I do with this result to go to the final answer. I may look stupid but I am blind and my screen teller  does not work properly (I have to get a new one).  Would the result be independent of $a$ and $b$ ? Thanks agaib (please help me more !!). Cheers :-)

Comment: Sorry, in the first version of my answer I evaluateted `int[Pi]`. See my modified answer!

Comment: This is superb ! Thanks  so much.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hope it helps!

Comment: Much more than that. I shall update my answer on MSE

Comment: -1. The answer is completely incorrect from math point of view. The substitution `Tan[k]->tank` makes `Tan[k]` to be a constant `tank` independent on `k`.

Comment: Also `int = Values@
  DSolve[{f'[k] == (a Sin[k]^2 + b)/
       Sqrt[(a Sin[k]^2 + b)^2 + Sin[k]^2], f[0] == 0}, f, k][[1, 1]]` produces "DSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential or integral equations of the given functions."

Comment: @user64494 As is so often the case, your comment is hasty and inconsequential

Comment: @user64494 In addition, user Leibovici was able to evaluate and understand my code

Answer (score 1):

The limit is given by a rather complicated function of a and b containing complete Elliptic functions as:

```
(b*((b*(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b]) + a*(1 + Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b]))*
EllipticK[(2*Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b])/(1 + 2*b*(a + b) + 
Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b])] + b*(1 + 2*a*(a + b) - Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b])*
EllipticPi[(1 + 2*a*(a + b)+Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b])/(2*(1 + (a + b)^2)), 
(2*Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b])/(1 + 2*b*(a + b) + Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b])]))/
(a*(1 + 2*b*(a + b) + Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b])*
Sqrt[b*(a + b) + (1/2)*(1 + Sqrt[1 + 4*a*b])])
```

I obtained it by transforming the imaginary argument of the incomplete elliptic functions returned by Mathematica into real form as well as applying a transformation for imaginary moduli (negative values in Mathematica speak)

Comment: Superb ! Thank you so much.

Comment: When I think about my ridiculous asymptotics !! If you have time to waste, ask Mathematica for it : a pure monster !!

Comment: @Andreas It would be very helpful if you show the solution steps which led to your result!

Comment: They go like EllipticF[I*zz, kk^2] -> I*EllipticF[ArcTan[Sinh[zz]], 1 - kk^2] and
EllipticF[zz, -kk] -> EllipticF[ArcTan[Sqrt[1 + kk]*Tan[zz]], kk/(1 + kk)]/Sqrt[1 + kk]

Comment: @Andreas In addition case `  {b -> 1, a -> 0}` should evaluate to `EllipticK[-1]` but your formula gives `Indeterminate`!

Comment: do g=limit[formula,b->1] and then Series[g,{a,0,1}] and you get EllipticK[-1]

Comment: @Andreas In your comment you show the asymptotics of `EllipticcF[...]`. How did you simplify the part `EllipticPi[...]`?

Comment: Additional transformations are found in https://dlmf.nist.gov §19.7

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the interesting link. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the information concerning the asymptotics `Asymptotic[EllipticPi[c1,I inf,c2],inf->Infinity]` .I still think it's a pity that you only give a result without  offering  solution steps

Comment: Well, it's quite an involved procedure: Transform the EllipticF and EllipticPi, first their imaginary arguments with replacements found on the site given in the link. Then treat the modulus correspondingly until 0<k^2<1. After that the limit resulting in complete elliptic integrals is easy. The thing took me 2 hours and the notebook with all steps explained would give a rather long answer...